# Any jquery plugin which automatic update time for all the posts of a page

Tags: jquery

I have a page having lots of posts showing time when they were posted. I want to keep on updating that time after every 1 min. One simple way can be give them a same class and get all the elements after 1 min and update the time. Any better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple plugin like this:

```
$.fn.UpdateSince = function(interval) {

    var times = this.map(function(){ return { e: $(this), t: parseInt($(this).html()) }; });

    var format = function(t) {
        if (t > 60) {
            return Math.floor(t / 60) + ' minutes ago'
        } else {
            return t + ' seconds ago';
        }
    }

    var update = function(){
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        $.each(times, function(i, o){
            o.e.html(format(Math.round((now - o.t) / 1000)));
        });
    };

    window.setInterval(update, interval);
    update();

    return this;
}
```

It sets up a function that runs at an interval and updates the elements that you specify. The elements originally contain the time in integer format, i.e. milliseconds since 1970-01-01:

```
<div class="TimeSince">1314952218779</div>
```

Usage:

```
$('.TimeSince').UpdateSince(1000);
```

The parameter is the update interval in milliseconds. `1000` is once a second, so if you display the time in minutes you would use a larger value, for example every 20 seconds, or `20 * 1000`.

The part you would want to improve is the function `format`, which turns seconds into a human readable format. It now has minutes and seconds ago, but you probably want something like, days, hours or minutes ago.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/7EsAX/

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is to have the same selector for all the elements of the posts that need to show the time and update theyr value every x seconds.

**UPDATE** :
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nbTer/3/) is a live demo using the above method.
It is available in the form of a jquery plugin too.

Answer (score 0):

jquery.timago.js is your friend. You can find it here: http://timeago.yarp.com/