# Nan error in Safari while using time update script

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, nan

I was trying to use the post time updating script posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280795/any-jquery-plugin-which-automatic-update-time-for-all-the-posts-of-a-page). It works great, except that on Mobile Safari it generates NAN errors. I tried to print out each of the variables to see where the NAN is coming from, but no dice. If somebody could possibly help me figure out where the error is generated I should be able to figure out a fix. Or even help me figure out how I could best find where the error is coming from.  The actual code is below.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
$.fn.UpdateSince = function(interval) {

var times = this.map(function(){ return { e: $(this), t: parseInt($(this).html()) }; });
var format = function(t) {
    if (t > 60) {
        return Math.floor(t / 60) + ' minutes ago'
    } else {
        return t + ' seconds ago';
    }
}

var update = function(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    $.each(times, function(i, o){
        o.e.html(format(Math.round((now - o.t) / 1000)));
    });
};            
window.setInterval(update, interval);
update();

return this;
}
}); 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.TimeSince').UpdateSince(1000);
}); 
</script>
```

Edit: Mobile Safari debug console shows no errors, but all output integers are NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's here:

```
var times = this.map(function(){ return { e: $(this), t: parseInt($(this).html()) }; });
```

If `$(this).html()` is empty, it will fail.

Comment: I was narrowing in on that. Let's see if I can rework that. If so, I will post my solution.

Comment: You can probably use this to prevent it: parseInt("0"+$(this).html(),10)

Comment: Would you expect that to make it work as expected or just suppress the NaN error? I tried that and got some funky results. A little more tinkering ....  What is the need for the 10 after the html(), ?

Comment: We're adding the zero to make sure there's a value if the HTML is blank. parseInt() assumes you're using OCTAL if you have a string starting with zero. the ",10" forces it to use decimal mode.

Comment: Works fine in IE, FIrefox, Chrome. In Mobile Safari it is acting as if the value it is getting is 0, ie, it is not getting the proper value but at least it isn't printing out NaN everywhere.  Is that what was intended or should the above code be getting the proper value?

Comment: Well, I just swapped out .html with .text and it all works just fine now. Still testing, but it seems to work now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, when I went to integrate with the web app I am working on I ended up totally changing the process by which the time gets brought into the script. I just decided to echo the timestamp in the id attribute and replaced parseInt($(this).html with: parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('asked_time-','')  Works like a charm.