# auto time increment like on facebook (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay , im want to make something like facebook's auto time increment for posts and notificaitons etc.
when the post arrived for example , 5 seconds ago.

How do i use jQuery to make it auto increase without having to parse server for timeago.

It can increase till hours and days.

I have found a script , and tried modifying it , but its not working:
[Any jquery plugin which automatic update time for all the posts of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280795/any-jquery-plugin-which-automatic-update-time-for-all-the-posts-of-a-page)

```
$.fn.UpdateSince = function(interval) {

    var times = this.map(function(){ return { e: $(this), t: parseInt($(this).html()) }; });

    var format = function(t) {
        if (t > 60) {
            return Math.floor(t / 60) + ' minutes ago'
        } else if(t > 3600){
            return Math.floor(t / 3600) + ' hours ago'
        } else if(t > 86400){
            return Math.floor(t / 86400) + ' days ago'
        } else {
            return t + ' seconds ago';
        }
    }

    var update = function(){
        $.each(times, function(i, o){
            o.e.html(format(Math.round((o.t + 1000))));
        });
    };

    window.setInterval(update, interval);
    update();

    return this;
}

$('.TimeSince').UpdateSince(1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you removed the `now` variable from the original script, which needs to know what time it is in order to run!

The `getTime()` method returns a value from your system clock - not the server.

Incidentally, you should reverse the order of the conditional in your code - put "days" first, then "hours", then "minutes":

```
if(t > 86400) {
    return Math.floor(t / 86400) + ' days ago';
} else if(t > 3600) {
    return Math.floor(t / 3600) + ' hours ago';
} else if(t > 60) {
    return Math.floor(t / 60) + ' minutes ago';
} else {
    return t + ' seconds ago';
}
```

Otherwise, the function will always return "seconds" if `t` is greater than `60`.

Comment: i see , can you give me an exmaple , for example now my post time is 5 seconds(original time) , how can i make it increment using the script?

Comment: thanks , however i notice something odd , the .timesince , is in millisecond format? when i type in 1000 , it shows 15701 days ago , but 1000milliseconds is 1 second right? it should start increase to 2 , 3 , 4 and so on. please correct me , im lost lol.

Comment: It STARTS OUT (ie supplied from the server) as UTC format, and the code *subtracts* the current UTC time from the original time. Most web apps would find it easiest to supply the original posting date in UTC format. It's replaced with the actual "time since" by the script.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Answer (score 2):

There'a already a pretty good plugin called [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) that does just this.

Just include it:

```
<script src="jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And add some code:

```
$('abbr.timeago').timeago();
```

Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

Comment: thanks , i know the plugin , just im looking for a much smaller one like the one above.

Comment: @sm21guy: Have you seen how big that plugin is? It's tiny: http://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js. When you minify it, it'll be even smaller.